# Very bottom level export of a .js failing

Tags: javascript, node.js

what would make the bottom level export fail in a js file? this format is used to , give another file access to code on the exported file `"export default file1.js"`

here is the stack trace

```
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (210:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| const FILE1Manager = {};
| export default file1.js;
|
```

Comment: in case you had already read my answer, I updated it to provide some explanation around Why you got that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it looks like you want to "re-export" the exports in `file1.js`.

`export default file1.js` is the wrong way to do it.

You can re-export everything except the "default" export of the `file1.js` with:

```
export * from 'file1.js';
```

If the file you want to export has a "default" export of its own, then you need to add this as well:

```
export { default } from 'file1.js';
```

There are other variations to it, you can see options with explanations in the [exploringjs site](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_re-exporting)

**Update 1** Adding explanation of the error message.

Reading your question, I think you may have a misunderstanding of *top level* exports, so I am adding some context regarding that error message.

Top Level does not mean its *position* in the file, it is hinting towards where in the *code structure* it can be placed. Top Level thus implies it must be available to be executed when module loader is parsing your module.

```
// wrapped within a conditional block. 
// This is not a Top Level, as first it has to evaluate the conditional
if (x === y) {
   import * from 'a'
}
// this is top level, even if placed anywhere: 
import * from 'a'
```

In your export statement, you were missing the `from` directive to the `export`, so the module loader would think, I will have to execute something to gather the exports, thus it is not a `Top Level` instruction.